# Is possible apply a mask in a Quad obj (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, mask, mesh

everyone. I'm working on an SM project, but in my logic, my elements use a Mesh Renderer instead of a Sprite Renderer, and now I'm having difficulties applying a mask to them.

Alright, I tried to use a Sprite Renderer, but since my code was written with the Mesh Renderer in mind, there are many bugs when switching. I would like to know if it's possible to use a mask for the Mesh Renderer.